# google-app-maker - App Maker will soon deprecate the foreign key field. We recommend you use relations instead

Tags: google-app-maker

Appmaker saying

> App Maker will soon deprecate the foreign key field. We recommend you
>   use relations instead.

What does it mean? Does it mean they are going to remove FK from Database tables or are they going to hide FK so developer/user cannot directly use it in app to enforce to use Relation.

Comment: Deprecated means that the function is in the process of being replaced by something new and often better, so if you use a deprecated function you can not be sure if it will work in the future ... it might but also might be not so its recommended to use the new one to be sure :)

Comment: The replacement is already available and is what they refer to as the relation API which is specific to app maker. The documentation here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/relations gives you a general idea of how to use it, and I am sure you are probably already using it. Since these are SQL tables we are talking about, the FK field will still be available, however it will only be able to be accessed through calculated SQL datasources. Otherwise, wherever you may have a reference to `YourTable.YourRelation_fk` will essentially have to be replaced with `YourTable.YourRelation.Id`.

Comment: True that is what i am thinking but wanted to make sure.. Thank you.